# Laravel validation Error messages to string

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to convert laravel validation error array to a comma separated string. This is to use in an api service for an ios application. So that the iOs developer can process error messages easily.

I tried,

```
    $valArr = [];
    foreach ($validator->errors() as $key => $value) { 
        $errStr = $key.' '.$value[0];
        array_push($valArr, $errStr);
    }
    if(!empty($valArr)){
        $errStrFinal = implode(',', $valArr);
    }
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should do like this :

```
$errorString = implode(",",$validator->messages()->all());
```

P.S. Assuming

```
$validator = Validator::make($dataToBeChecked,$validationArray,$messageArray)
```

Comment: also for other MessageBags like `$validator->errors()->all()`

Answer (score 5):

```
You are not converting validation errors to array.Please use the below function and pass validation errors as parameter.

 public function validationErrorsToString($errArray) {
        $valArr = array();
        foreach ($errArray->toArray() as $key => $value) { 
            $errStr = $key.' '.$value[0];
            array_push($valArr, $errStr);
        }
        if(!empty($valArr)){
            $errStrFinal = implode(',', $valArr);
        }
        return $errStrFinal;
    }
//Function call.
$result = $this->validationErrorsToString($validator->errors());
```

Answer (score 5):

The `$validator->errors()` returns a `MessageBag`,

see: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html.

You are close, you need to call the `getMessages()` function on `errors()`, so:

```
foreach ($validator->errors()->getMessages() as $key => $value) {
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it like me without your validator and you are pulling messages from the exception you can use laravel helper `Arr::flatten($array);`

Link and code are for laravel 8.x but I tested this with 5.7 ;) It works.

From [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-flatten):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = ['name' => 'Joe', 'languages' => ['PHP', 'Ruby']];

$flattened = Arr::flatten($array);

// ['Joe', 'PHP', 'Ruby']
```

My code:

```
try {
  $request->validate([
    'test1' => 'required|integer',
    'test2' => 'required|integer',
    'test3' => 'required|string',
  ]);
} catch (ValidationException $validationException) {
  return response()->json([
    'type' => 'error',
    'title' => $validationException->getMessage(),
    'messages' => Arr::flatten($validationException->errors())
  ], $validationException->status);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
  return response()->json([
    'type' => 'error',
    'title' => $exception->getMessage(),
  ], $exception->getCode());
}
```

As you can see I am pulling the message and setting it as my title. Then I am using `Arr::flatten($validationException->errors())` to get the validation messages and but to flatten my array for SweetAlert2 on the frontend.

I know I am late but I hope it will help someone that comes across these problems.

Greetings! :)