# How to get Validation errors as an array of string?

Tags: php, laravel

I have form which i validate in controller when validate fails i got errors by using $myValidator->errors() which returns object of Messagebag but i want only error messages as an array of string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel validation Error messages to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517760/laravel-validation-error-messages-to-string)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To retrieve all errors as an array strings for all fields, you can use the [`all()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#working-with-error-messages) method.

Like so:

```
$myValidator->errors()->all();
```